# How can I use switch statements to display number on a 7-segment display?

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement, microprocessors

So, this might be a microntroller question, but I have trouble with the code, so I thought there may be someone who can at least give me a hint to all this.
I am trying connect a potentiometer to a 7segment display, which takes in 2V(minimum) to 3.3V (maximum). How can I connect the ATD (potentiometer) value to switch cases?

```
void light7segment(unsigned int cnt)       //convert ATD value
{
 
    
}
```

The code above is a function that will take in the ATD value and use the case statement from set_7segment() in light7segment.

```
void main ()
{
  unsigned int i;
  
 
    //Insert Application Software Here
    for (;;){     
    i= Atd0.atddr[8].d10;       //get ATD value
     
    light7segment(i);   // display ATD value on 7-seg
    
    }
        
    for (;;);
}




void set_7segment(unsigned char number) 
{
  switch (number) 
  {
    case 0 : 
      Pim.pth.byte=0b00111111;      //display 0 in 7-seg
      break;  
    case 1 : 
      Pim.pth.byte=0b00000110;      //display 1 in 7-seg
      break;
    case 2 : 
      Pim.pth.byte=0b01011011;      //display 2 in 7-seg
      break;
    case 3 : 
      Pim.pth.byte=0b01001111;      //display 3 in 7-seg
      break;
    case 4 : 
      Pim.pth.byte=0b01100110;      //display 4 in 7-seg
      break;
    case 5 : 
      Pim.pth.byte=0b01101101;      //display 5 in 7-seg
      break;
    case 6 : 
      Pim.pth.byte=0b01111101;      //display 6 in 7-seg
      break;
    case 7 : 
      Pim.pth.byte=0b00100111;      //display 7 in 7-seg
      break;
    case 8 : 
      Pim.pth.byte=0b01111111;      //display 8 in 7-seg
      break;                                        
    case 9 : 
      Pim.pth.byte=0b01101111;      //display 9 in 7-seg
      break;
    case 10 :
      Pim.pth.byte=0b00000000;      //turn off 7-seg
      break;  
    default:
      break;
  }
  return; 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a lookup table for what you want to do?

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 I'm sorry I've never heard of a lookup table. Could you explain what it is?

Comment: If you google for a lookup table you should find many sources. But basically it's an array with the correct values at the right indexes. So for example you could create a `static const char display[] = {0b00111111, 0b00000110, ...}` and then just do `Pim.pth.byte = display[number]` It's a bit hard to explain in a comment, do look it up properly.

Comment: y=mx+c with  no m and no c:(

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn’t terribly clear - it seems to be more along the lines of "How do I map the current pot value onto the range `0..10`?"

Since `10` corresponds to OFF, I'm going to assume you only want to map the digitized pot value `0` to `10`.  In that case, it's a matter of mapping `1..max_pot_value` to `0..9`, although we'll just map `0...max_pot_value` onto that range and have a special case for `0`.

The way to do that is to take your max pot value and divide that by 10 - that gives you the size of each bucket.  Then you divide your incoming pot value by that bucket size.  Assuming your ATD values are `0..2047`, you'd have a bucket size of `204`<sup>1</sup>, so everything from `0` to `203` maps to `0`, `204` to `407` maps to `1`, etc.

```
#define MAX_POT_VALUE 2047 // replace with the actual max value

void light_7segment( unsigned int cnt )
{
  unsigned int stepSize = MAX_POT_VALUE / 10;
  unsigned int map = cnt ? cnt/stepSize : 10; // if cnt != 0, then map = cnt/stepSize, otherwise map = 10

  set_7segment( (unsigned char) map );
}
```

*Personally*, I would use a lookup table instead of a `switch` statement:

```
void set_7segment( unsigned char number )
{
  unsigned char segValue[11] = {
    0b00111111,
    0b00000110,
    ...
  };

  Pim.pth.byte = segValue[number];
}
```

but either way works.

---

1. Integer division yields an integer result - `1/2 == 0`, `3/2 == 1`, etc.

Comment: I would prefer a `static` array for a lookup table instead. Maybe for 11 values it isn't too bad, but with bigger arrays, they would have to be created every single time the function would be called, which might be bad for speed.